# What is an efficient data structure to store multiple variable-sized sets of numbers?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, multidimensional-array, data-structures

I have multiple sets of numbers, like so:

Set 1: 1,2,3,5,4,3,2,1

Set 2: 1,2,1,1

Set 3: 1,1,1,0

Set 4: 1,9

The number of sets will be specified by the user, and also how many numbers each set may contain. Then, the program will randomly populate the values.

Right now, I am using a 2D array with dimensions

```
[maximum(set-sizes)][maximum(elements_in_set)]
```

and setting the unused cells with a large negative number to indicate that they are not of use.
Although this serves my purpose, I was wondering if there is a better data structure that I can use.

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: @Rapid Python 2

Comment: "Efficient" can mean many things. Are you more concerned with speed, or with space usage? Do you care how long it takes to build, as long as access is fast? How many of these sets do you have, and how large are they? Is this something you're going to do once, and then throw it away, or is it going to be an integral part of a high-performance system that will be used on a regular basis?

Comment: I have a maximum of 10 sets, and each of them can have a maximum of 10 numbers. I want to be able to build this fast, as this is something I am going to use just once. Also, I am more concerned with speed.

Comment: 10 sets with a maximum of 10 numbers in each set results in a maximal total identity number of 100, which is by no means a great issue for modern computer both temporally and spatially even if you use a 2-d matrix to process.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a list of lists:

```
>>> numbers = [
...     [1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
...     [1, 2, 1, 1],
...     [1, 1, 1, 0],
...     [1, 9]
... ]

>>> numbers[3]
[1, 9]
```

Note that what you describe are not sets, because they have no order and can contain every element only once.